# How does my password manager know that the password I am setting has been previously exposed in a data breach?

Tags: security, passwords

My password managing software, (aka my password-vault), is able to tell me when the password I am using, for any given account, has been exposed by a data breach. This feature doesn't seem exclusive to password managers though, as I had a web-site (I can't remember which one it was) decline the password I choose for a new user I was creating, due to the password having been previously exposed in a data breach.

---

###### The image below shows the insensitive part of an alert-style warning notification that I received from my password manager "Bitwarden" today.

[image: Warning-Mesg]

The password that triggered the warning notification is one I use for creating accounts with sites that I don't fully trust, know much about, or only need an account for a one-time login. Because of which password I used, and what I use it for, I was not very surprised to learn it had been exposed in a DB breach. I would like to know more about the breach that my password was exposed in though. It may not even have been me who was using the password. So, I guess what I really want to know, is this following:

How are some websites, and some security software managing to find out if a password was exposed in a breach? I know Bitwarden is opensource, and the source code is public, so does that mean that there is a public database that anyone can query with a password & find out if the queried password has been exposed or not?

Comment: short answer, yes. There are a few databases that can be interfaced with. A popular one would be haveibeenpwned.com

Comment: Bitwarden uses the same API as mentioned in [this article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/validating-leaked-passwords-with-k-anonymity/)

Comment: @mashuptwice What a fascinating article. This is exactly the information I was looking for. It's very well written. Thank you sir MashupTwice

Comment: @LPChip From reading mashupTwices article, it sounds like haveIbeenPawned.com & Bitwarden both use the same API.

Comment: Definatly bookmarking https://www.haveIbeenpawned.com thank you @LPChip